# 2D arrays. First index wrong, all others correct

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2010, pointers

I have a weird problem and I'm not sure how to approach it.

I'm reading a 50x50 chars textfile and want to write it into a 50x51 dynamic array (filling the 51th slot with '\0').

Afterwards I'm printing the entire array onto the console.
It should show 50 lines with 50 chars each, as this was the input.

It works quite well too - with the exception of the first line. For some reason is always wrong.

```
#define FIELD_SIZE 50
int main(int argc, char** args){
    char* data = ReadFile("start.txt");

    char** map = (char**) malloc( FIELD_SIZE );

    if(map==NULL)
        __debugbreak();

    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i+=1){
            map[i] = (char*) malloc(FIELD_SIZE+1);

            if(map[i]==NULL)
                __debugbreak();
            //(FIELD_SIZE+1) in order to skip the '\n' at the end of each line.
            memcpy( &map[i][0], &data[i*(FIELD_SIZE+1)], FIELD_SIZE);
            map[i][FIELD_SIZE] = '\0';
        }
    }


    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < FIELD_SIZE; i+=1){
            printf("%s\n", map[i]); //<-- prints something bad for i==0
        }
    }

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's how my console looks like after program execution:
[image]
The first line is supposed to be "aaaaaaaaaaaaa..." too.
So it seems like a bad pointer or something.

If I'm reducing FIELD_SIZE to 20 instead (and reading in a 20x20 text file respectively) it works fine, however.

I don't see a connection between the array size and the first index not working though. Since malloc never returned 0 there's no problem with allocation.

I'm using VS2010 C++ to compile the program, but I have to limit myself to the C subset.

Comment: Are you sure your file's all good?

Comment: The file is an ANSI-encoded regular text file (with np++). It just contains 20 rows of 20 a's each. Since all but the first row works I don't think the problem directly lies in reading the file. And as I said, if I reduce FIELD_SIZE everything works, so it's not a "hidden" problematic character or similar in the file.

Comment: Added image to post so future visitors can understand question even if the referenced image site is no longer valid.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you print out the line right after reading it into your array?

Comment: @Michael - that actually prints the correct string. So there's proof that it's not the file reading where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

char** map = (char**) malloc( FIELD_SIZE );

char** map = (char**) malloc( FIELD_SIZE * sizeof(char*));

I don't know if this would be the bug in your code.
You allocate 50 bytes, but need 50 bytes x 4 bytes/pointer in map.

Comment: Stupid me. Yes, that's it, I forgot the char*. Nasty that it only bugged out the first slot.

Comment: if you had a test cast such as
'abcdefghijkalalsdkfmasdl' i.e. a lot of random characters it might of popped up instead of a bunch of a's.
The random string would potentially show the mismatched address I would hope, but still a pain in the butt to nail something like this down after a long day of codin'.

Comment: `char **map = malloc(FIELD_SIZE * sizeof *map);` would be better.  The cast isn't necessary (in C) and just adds noise.  The type of `*map` is `char *`; not that you ever will, but if you changed the type of `map`, you wouldn't have to worry about replicating that change in the `malloc` call.

Comment: @John Bode the cast is neccessary, thats first, sizeof *map `is` noise, thats second

Comment: @Ulterior - the cast hasn't been necessary in C since C89; a `void *` can be converted to any other object pointer type without one. It's still necessary in C++, but you shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++ code. And my rationale for `sizeof *map` still stands; if you change the type of `map`, you don't have to replicate the change in the `malloc` call.

Comment: @JohnBode I'm using VS2010 to compile the code, so technically it's C++ code. So I'll add the casts to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: @s3rius: Huh.  I thought VS could do straight C code.  I don't work on Windows or with MS tools, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was wrong on that score.  If you're writing C++, there are far better (and less annoying) ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @JohnBode It is a homework excercise. We were only allowed to use C. I'm using VS because I'm used to working with it. VS has a switch to strictly compile C, but I think it's pure C98 so there are annoying restrictions like having to declare all variables at the top of functions. I would rejoice if only I were allowed to write this in Cpp :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick thing to notice. It's probably useless in this context. Memcpy will take for its source the address of the pointer not the refrenced value so in general you shouldn't use it the way you are. From what I can tell you're trying to copy a row at a time.

```
memcpy( map[i], &data[i*(FIELD_SIZE+1)], FIELD_SIZE);
```

Try that, although it's probably not going to fix your issue.